# WP7 Have the enter key send text from textbox to a textblock

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, keyboard, windows-phone-7

The [following tutorial](http://tech-fyi.net/2010/07/21/wp7-hello-world/) shows how to take the text from a text box and display it in a text block when the user hits a button. Simple enough... but what I want to do is instead of hitting a button that adds the text I want the enter button to do it.

Searching here, I found the following code but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

So, the textbox that has the string is called textbox and I want the text from that textbox to be added to my list (listBox). When I click the enter button, it does nothing. Any help?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at the line with the if statement, debug, then look at e.Key to see what key is being registered.

Comment: yeah, it never gets called. I am loving breakpoints btw. Is there some way to call the keyboard in wp7? I can set an even for like a button press, but what about a keyboard press?  hmmm let me look around, that breakpoint suggestion has got me on the right track.

Answer (score 6):

You can intercept the enter key from the on screen keyboard, but not from the keyboard of a PC running the emulator.

Here's some code to prove it works:

Create a new Phone Application.
Add the following to the content grid

```
<ListBox Height="276" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,84,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
```

Then in the code behind, add the following:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: He made it very clear that he is clicking the enter key so he is not using the keyboard on the PC. In addition your code is EXACTLY the same as the one he states doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wire this event handler to the textboxes KeyDown event if you haven't done so already. You can do so via the Events tab in the properties window, while the textbox is targeted - or you can double click there and VS will create a new event handler for you which you can put the above code into.

Comment: Wouldn't the code I have in my post do that? It is hooked into the xaml page as well.

Comment: Not by just adding the method. You need to wire the event to the method using one of the techniques I mentioned.

Comment: +1 from his comments this seems this is the answer, too bad he didn't select this (or any) as the answer

Answer (score 0):

@Court from the answer you gave @Trees i can assume you are not really sure if the `KeyDown` is wired. Do you have the following code in the XAML file?

```
<TextBox Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,-2,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" KeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown" />
```

@Matt Lacey intercepting Enter from the PC's keyboard also works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to handle the KeyUp event instead.